# XPATH instructions

Tags: xml, xpath, odoo

I would like to add a field right after the user_id field

I tried this but unfortunately, it doesn't work, can someone indicate me what changes that it still be done?

```
<xpath expr="/form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Other Information']//group[@string='Sales Information']/field[@name='user_id']" position="after">
     <field name="my_field"/>
</xpath>
```

**View arch**:

```
<page string="Other Information">
<group>
    <group string="Sales Information" name="sales_person">
        <field name="user_id"/>
        <field name="team_id" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
        <field name="client_order_ref"/>
        <field name="company_id" options="{'no_create': True}" groups="base.group_multi_company"/>
        <field name="project_id" attrs="{'invisible':[('state','=','sale')]}" context="{'default_partner_id':partner_invoice_id, 'default_name':name}" groups="analytic.group_analytic_accounting"/>
        <field name="related_project_id" attrs="{'readonly': ['|',('project_id','!=',False),('invoice_count','!=',0),('state','=','sale')],'invisible':[('state','!=','sale')]}" context="{'default_partner_id':partner_invoice_id, 'default_name':name}" groups="analytic.group_analytic_accounting"/>
    </group>
    <group name="sale_pay" string="Invoicing">
        <field name="fiscal_position_id" options="{'no_create': True}"/>
        <field name="invoice_status" attrs="{'invisible': [('state', 'not in', ('sale','done'))]}"/>
    </group>
    <!-- ***** THIS ONE ****** -->
    <group string="Reporting" name="technical" groups="base.group_no_one">
        <field groups="base.group_no_one" name="origin"/>
    </group>
    <!-- ***** THIS ONE ****** -->
</group>
```

Answer (score 2):

You can face less of this XPath issues if you use the // accessor whenever is possible for example, for that view you can use

`//page[@string='Other Information']//group[@string='Sales Information']/field[@name='user_id']`

```html
<xpath expr="//page[@string='Other Information']//group[@string='Sales Information']/field[@name='user_id']" position="after">
        <field name="my_field"/>
</xpath>
```

The `//` accessor is not one to use without care anyway, because it has a performance cost, but for simple views you can use it without too much problem.

Answer (score 0):

Try the following:

```
<xpath expr="//form/sheet/notebook/page[@string='Other Information']/group/group[@string='Sales Information']/field[@name='user_id']" position="after">
    <field name="my_field"/>
</xpath>
```